# Get datetime filteration rows in SQL by using month and year

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have my table with a `datetime` column in SQL Server. Now I want to filter the table on that `datetime` column by using it's month and year.

If I have the complete `datetime` format, I am able to set up `>` or `<` in that query but by using month with year filter, I am not sure how to do that.

Please suggest me how can we do the filter on the table?

Table details:

- Table Name : `Sales`
- `DateTime` column: `Created Date` (yy/mm/dd)

Stored procedure parameters:

@MinimumMonth int,
   @MaximumMonth int,
   @MinimumYear int,
   @MaximumYear int,

These are all the values I can send it through my stored procedure parameters, now I need to form dateformat as Minimonth/Miniyear and Maxmonth/MaxYear and need to filter the records based between these mini amd max mm/yy ranges..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

There is a few things that you should consider in this case.

1. CreatedDate should be an Indexed field
2. You should avoid applying functions on indexed fields, because it causes index to be in-effective.
3. You also need to consider time component if the CreatedDate field is a datetime field

   ```
   DECLARE @MinimumMonth INT = 1
   DECLARE @MaximumMonth int = 12
   DECLARE @MinimumYear INT = 2014
   DECLARE @MaximumYear INT = 2016

   DECLARE @MinDate Date
   DECLARE @MaxDate Date
   DECLARE @TempDate Date

   SET @MinDate = Convert(date, '01/'+ CAST(@MinimumMonth AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(@MinimumYear AS varchar),103)
   SET @TempDate = Convert(date,'01/'+ CAST(@MaximumMonth AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(@MaximumYear AS varchar),103)
   SET @MaxDate = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@TempDate)+1,0))  
   --print @MaxDate

   SELECT * FROM Sales 
   WHERE 
   CreatedDate >= @MinDate AND CreatedDate <= @MaxDate
   ```

Comment: This is really worked . Excellent! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `MONTH()` and `YEAR()` to get exact Month or Year from your column.

```
SELECT * FROM Sales 
WHERE 
(MONTH(CreatedDate) Between @MinimumMonth AND @MaximumMonth) 
AND 
(YEAR(CreatedDate) Between @MinimumYear AND @MaximumYear)
```

Hope this help

Comment: The MONTH() and YEAR() functions are not sargable, though, meaning this query wouldn't be able to use an index on the CreatedDate column, and worse, will force the database to evaluate the functions on every row in the table. Constructing dates to compare >= and < is a **much** better approach.